# Nuxtjs with scrollmagic gives me "window is not defined"

Tags: window, undefined, scrollmagic, nuxt.js

I want to use scrollmagic with nuxtjs.

I installed scrollmagic via npm.

```
npm install scrollmagic
```

In my nuxt.config.js file i added

```
build: {
    vendor: ['scrollmagic']
},
```

And in my pages/index.vue file i simply imported it.

```
import ScrollMagic from 'scrollmagic'
```

But this results only in this error

> [vue-router] Failed to resolve async component default:
>   ReferenceError: window is not defined [vue-router] uncaught error
>   during route navigation: ReferenceError: window is not defined
>       at C:\pathto\node_modules\scrollmagic\scrollmagic\uncompressed\ScrollMagic.js:37:2
>       at C:\pathto\node_modules\scrollmagic\scrollmagic\uncompressed\ScrollMagic.js:22:20
>       at Object. (C:\pathto\node_modules\scrollmagic\scrollmagic\uncompressed\ScrollMagic.js:27:2)

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add a file to your plugins folder called "scrollmagic.js" and paste the following code into it:
**plugins/scrollmagic.js**

```
import ScrollMagic from 'scrollmagic'
```

Add the plugin to your nuxt.config.js file
**nuxt.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  build: {
    vendor: ['scrollmagic']
  },
  plugins: [
    // ssr: false to only include it on client-side
    { src: '~/plugins/scrollmagic.js', ssr: false }
  ]
}
```

Use it with `if (process.client) {}`
**page or component**

```
<script>
let scrollmagic
if (process.client) {
  scrollmagic = require('scrollmagic')
// use scrollmagic
}
</script>
```

For more information please consult the excellent documentation on this topic: https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins/

Comment: This solved the issue about "window is not defined" but now I'm getting this `ERROR calling setTween() due to missing Plugin 'animation.gsap'. Please make sure to include plugins/animation.gsap.js`. Have yet to find a solution for NuxtJS... Any idea on this?

Comment: Did you add a file to your plugins folder called "animation.gsap.js"? If so, are you sure that there are no typos?