# How to correct install vue-tags-input

Tags: nuxt.js

I installed http://www.vue-tags-input.com via npm and copied & pasted the code from "Getting Started" after this I received the message "Error Reference error window is not defined"

Problem is occurring during:
  `import VueTagsInput from '@johmun/vue-tags-input'`

The project is built on the nuxt.js framework. I tried set SSR Tag, import CDN.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47844836/nuxtjs-with-scrollmagic-gives-me-window-is-not-defined?rq=1 this is solution but to plugins instead node-module.

Answer (score 0):

To use a Vue package in a Nuxt project, it needs to be added to the project as a plugin, so after installing the vue-tags-input package, create a file in the plugins folder called `vue-tags-input.js` with this content.

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VueTagsInput from "@johmun/vue-tags-input";
Vue.use(VueTagsInput);
```

In your `nuxt.config.js` add this to the plugin array:  `{ src: "~plugins/vue-tag-input.js", ssr: false }`;

Now you can use the vue-tag-input component in your project. Example:

```
<vue-tags-input
   v-model="tag"
   :tags="tags"
   @tags-changed="(newTags) => (tags = newTags)"
/>
```